I am missing an input when I run xinput. Dualscreen set up with ONE touch screen that covers one of the two monitors. Ubuntu 20.04
I am running a dual screen kiosk, one side is a touch screen, the other is passive. Typically for this type of setup, I run XINPUT and XRANDR and map the touch screen to the correct monitor. Below will have the results of that, and an example of the .sh file that I typically put in the startup so it will work after a reboot. This time I have a one off monitor with an IR touch screen, when I run xinput, no touch screen shows up in the list. I know that the computer sees the touch screen does input, because I can click and drag, but it is in the wrong orientation and spread across multiple screens. Any suggestions as to how to find the touch screen and map it to the particular monitor?
eyeon@np-center-ul-ser5:~$ xinput

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
> ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer 
> (2)]
>               viid=9ouch[slave  pointer  (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
>     ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>     ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>     ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>     ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>               viid=10uch[slave  keyboard (3)]

eyeon@np-center-ul-ser5:~$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2160 x 1920, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1210mm x 681mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-A-0 connected 1080x1920+1080+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
   3840x2160     45.00 +  60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1200     45.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

eyeon@np-center-ul-ser5:~$ 

This is what I would put in the .sh file,mapping the id number to the screen if there was a touch screen, but there is not a touch screen to map to.
sleep 4 && xinput map-to-output 4 DisplayPort-0&

Any suggestions?
